# center element in all media screen in specific div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i'm working in design using bootstrap framework 
and i face problem with some screen sizes as this website is responsive 
i can solve this problem by target every media but i think that there are a solution by using defined class with bootstrap 
the problem i just want to center some element in center in all media screen ,to explain it i prefer using images
in the large screen thre's no problem 
[image]

but in other media 
[image]

this is code hint

```
 <div class="socialicons center-block">
                 <a href="#"><i id="social-user" class="fa fa-facebook-square fa-2x social-fb"></i></a>
                <a href="#"><i id="social-user" class="fa fa-twitter-square fa-2x social-tw"></i></a>
                <a href="#"><i id="social-user" class="fa fa-google-plus-square fa-2x social-gp"></i></a>
                <a href="#"> <i id="social-user" class="fa fa-linkedin-square fa-2x social-tw"></i></a>
            </div>
```

i tried this css

```
display: block;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
```

and 
margin :0 auto;

Comment: not sure i follow, it looks like they are centered in their parent.  are you looking for then to show up horizontally in a row? if so you will need to not use display block, instead use inline-block and have text-align: center; on the parent

Comment: Hey only change the `display:block` to `display:table` then it work fine

Comment: change .socialicons as @amitrh indicates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for your comments guys 
i made as @amitrh indicates and this work fine with the first block of items and works like this in all screen 
[image]

and the links appear in center as i want and in block by apply this code

```
.socialicons {
    display: table;
    margin: auto;
```

for the second block in the last it have another bahavior as the font icons was bigger than the icons in the first like this 
[image]
and this too 
[image]
so i changed the css to

```
display: inline-table;
margin: auto;
```

and works fine and center in left in all screen like this 
[image]

thanks for your comments and code hints as you saved my time and this help me to solve my issue without css hacks or additional unnecessary code 
  @box86rowh  @amitrh   @BootstrapBoogie - Christina